# I can't modify a shulker box's items correctly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I ran into a possible bug with Minecraft 1.16.4.  I used the data command to modify the items of a shulker box to whatever helmet I'm wearing.  The command is the following.

```
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0] set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:103b}]
```

I am running the command manually.  It says the data is already the same.  My syntax is correct, but it just doesn't work.  The shulker box doesn't have the `Items` tag until I put an item in the container.  If I put an item in the shulker box and run the command, it just starts removing items out one by one and it doesn't give me an error.  I have in the past had a problem with the world I was using so I created a fresh world and it didn't solve anything.  Any help?  Is anyone else having the same problem?  Any workarounds?  Please ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is no bug; it is by design.

The command in question will also copy the slot number to the shulker box, causing the shulker box's data to look like this:

```
{Items:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:dirt",tag:{...}}]}
```

And `103` is an invalid slot number for shulker boxes. So what happens?

It gets deleted, automatically, and immediately.

To workaround this, use three `/data` commands: one to copy the item ID, one to copy the `Count` tag, and one to copy the `tag` compound. Basically, copy everything except the slot number.

```
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0]id set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:103b}].id
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0].Count set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:103b}].Count
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0].tag set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:103b}].tag
```

Comment: It works if a item is already in there thanks.

Comment: @randomuser922 Yes, and your original command also only works if an item is already in there, too.